# Missing mvvmlight templates after installation VS2015

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015, mvvm-light

Iam relative new to C# & WPF, I was just started to dive into WPF and I like to use mvvmlight as my framework. And Iam learning with a tutorial wich uses version 4.x (I want to use 5.x).

But after installing, I ain't get any templates for it, but I get the snippets.
I used the extension manager of VS2015 to install it. Also I tried to reinstall it with the codeplex version, none have me the templates I wanted.

I can use NuGet to install it on my solution, which gives me at least the basic solution to work with, but sadly that's only a work around.

Iam using Windows 7 64bit and VS2015 community edition.

Hopefully someone can help me out!

Regards Syli